# Is there a benefit to using "will-change" on the HTML5 video element?

Tags: css, performance, video, will-change

Is there any benefit on using the ***will-change*** property on an html ***video*** tag to increase performance ?

if so, how should i use it in order to make the video run on the GPU using Hardware Acceleration ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`will-change` is used to hint the browser, that a property or the content of the corresponding DOM-Element will likely change in the near future. Therefore it requires as value a CSS-property (e.g. `will-change: opacity`) or the `contents`keyword (`will-change: contents`).

If None of this is changed, I see no reason for using it on the video-tag.